# Trying To Make An Ajax Request and Use the Response in a React Componenet

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs

I have a `tweet box component` which has a `getAllTweets` function called on `submit`. The handle submit function`is supposed to capture the value of the field and pass it to the`getAllTweets function`so it the URL, so I can make a dynamic Ajax request. I am unable to save the variable containing the`handle` value and append it. Secondly, when I get the response I need to bind it to the TweetList Component. I can't get either to work..

```
var Tweet = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return (
      <div className="tweet">
        <h2 className="tweetAuthor">
          {this.props.handle}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TweetBox = React.createClass({
  getAllTweets: function(handle) {
    var handle = this.state.data;
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url + handle,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: tweet,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="tweetBox">
        <h1>Tweets</h1>
        <TweetList data={this.state.data} />
        <TweetForm onTweetSubmit={this.getAllTweets} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TweetList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var tweetNodes = this.props.data.map(function(tweet, index) {
      return (
        <Tweet handle={tweet.handle} key={index}>
          {tweet.message}
        </Tweet>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="tweetList">
        {tweetNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TweetForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var handle = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.handle).value.trim();
    if (!handle) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onTweetSubmit({handle: handle, message: message});
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.handle).value = '';
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="tweetForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="handle" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <TweetBox url="http://localhost:4000/api/"/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forget to declare the `message` variable in your TweetForm component.

> this.props.onTweetSubmit({handle: handle, message: message});

In your `getAllTweets` function, you pass in a `handle` variable and create another new `handle` variable again (`var handle = this.state.data`). That's why you can not get the tweet account name.

Don't use the same name to multiple variables in a method.